# how to place buttons side by side in uiview with Alignment center

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a uiview where I have to place few buttons side by side in the center of the uiview as shown in the figure programmatically

Similar to this figure.Buttons should be placed in the center of the uiview

```
 --------------------------------
| ----     ----      ----        |
||    |   |    |    |    |       |
|| 1B |   | 3B |    | 5B |       |
| ----     ----      ----        |
| ----     ----                  |
|| 2B |   |    |                 |
||    |   | 4B |                 |
| ----     ----                  |
 --------------------------------
```

Comment: you can implement your own logic.

Comment: how many buttons would you like to show? and each row contains how many buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something that I have worked out. [Source Code](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/35012982/Demo%20Projects/TestViewMatrix.zip)

An enumerated type to denote you want vertial or horizontally arranged items

```
typedef enum {
    ArrangementTypeHorz = 1,
    ArrangementTypeVert = 2
}ArrangementType;
```

Declared number or rows columns and arrangement type

```
@interface ATTViewController ()

{
    ArrangementType _arrangementType;

    NSUInteger _rows;
    NSUInteger _columns;

}

@end
```

Method calculates the frame of an item index wrt superView

```
- (CGRect)frameForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index inSuperView:(UIView *)superView
{
    CGFloat blockWidth  = floorf(superView.frame.size.width/_columns);
    CGFloat blockHeight = floorf(superView.frame.size.height/_rows);

    NSUInteger row    = 0;
    NSUInteger column = 0;

    if (_arrangementType == ArrangementTypeHorz) {
        row    = floorf((CGFloat)index/_columns);
        column = index - row*_columns;
    }else{
        column    = floorf((CGFloat)index/_rows);
        row = index - column*_rows;
    }

    CGFloat xOffset = 5.0f;
    CGFloat yOffset = 5.0f;

    return  CGRectMake(blockWidth*column+xOffset,
                       blockHeight*row+yOffset,
                       blockWidth-(2*xOffset),
                       blockHeight-(2*yOffset));
}
```

Adding Buttons to a containerView. While adding set the rows, columns and arrangementType

```
- (void)addButtonsToContainerView
{
    NSUInteger numberOfItems = 5;

    _rows = 2;
    _columns = 3;

    _arrangementType = ArrangementTypeVert;

    NSUInteger itemCount = 0;

    while (itemCount<numberOfItems)
    {
        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        CGRect frame = [self frameForItemAtIndex:itemCount inSuperView:self.containerView];
        [button setFrame:frame];
        NSString *title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Button %d",itemCount+1];
        [button setTitle:title forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        [self.containerView addSubview:button];

        itemCount ++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This method will create 4 buttons for Each row, same as PhotoGallery in IOS
Make Required Changes to Achieve your OUtput

```
-(void)createButtons
{
    int x, y, width, height, gapBetweenTwoButtons;
    x = y = 4;
    gapBetweenTwoButtons = 4;
    int numberOfButtons = 10;

    // i have calculated width for 4 columns it may vary for your requirement
    width = height = 140;

    // loop to create buttons
    UIButton *btn;

    for (int i=0; i< numberOfButtons; i++)
    {
        btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        [btn setFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width/2, height/2)];

        // Add button to scrollview
        [scrlViewSubCategory addSubview:btn];

        // calculate x and y accordingly
        if((i+1) % 4 == 0)
        {
            x = gapBetweenTwoButtons;
            y += (width/2)+gapBetweenTwoButtons;
        }
        else
            x += (width/2)+gapBetweenTwoButtons;
    }

    // finally , adjust content size of scrollview

    [scrlViewSubCategory setContentSize:CGSizeMake(scrlViewSubCategory.frame.size.width, (numberOfButtons/4) * ((width/2)+4))];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    -(void) fillGridViewAfterCall 
    {
            int count = [viewGrid.subviews count];
            for (int i = count-1; i >= 0; i--) 
            {
                    [[viewGrid.subviews objectAtIndex:i] removeFromSuperview];
            }
            int videoCount = 0;
            int posx = 10;
            int posy = 10;
            int mainLoopCount = ([arrUserVideos count]/3);

            if (([arrUserVideos count]%3) > 0) 
            {
                    mainLoopCount = mainLoopCount + 1;
            }

            for (int i=0; i<mainLoopCount; i++) 
            {
                    posx = 10;
                    for (int j=0; j<3; j++) 
                    {
                            VideoShare *shareObj = [arrUserVideos objectAtIndex:videoCount];

                            UIButton *btnVideo = [[[UIButton alloc] init];
                            btnVideo.frame = CGRectMake(posx, posy, 96, 96);
                            btnVideo.tag = shareObj.vdId;
                            btnVideo.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
                            btnVideo.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0;
                            [btnVideo setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"iconGridSelected.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                            [btnVideo addTarget:self action:@selector(btnGridVideoClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                            [viewGrid addSubview:btnVideo];
                            videoCount++;

                            if (videoCount == [arrUserVideos count]) 
                            {
                                    break;
                            }
                            posx = posx + 102;
                    }
                    posy = posy + 102;
            }

            if (arrUserVideos.count == 0) 
            {
                    viewGrid.hidden = YES;
            }
            else 
            {
                    viewGrid.frame = CGRectMake(0, posyDynamic, 320, (posy+5));
                    viewGrid.hidden = NO;
            }

            scrollObj.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, (viewGrid.frame.size.height+100+scrollIncrement));
    }
```